# mysql regexp two words enclosed with any special characters

Tags: mysql, regex

```
+-----+------+
|  A  |  B   |
+-----+------+
| gan | esh  |
| dhi | nesh |
+-----+------+
```

I have a table like this. I want to check this with another table has column

```
+----------------+
|       C        |
+----------------+
| !!dhin!!esh    |
| gan!!esh..     |
| $$$gan%%%esh.. |
+----------------+
```

The following query works fine

```
select * from table1 a, table2 b where c like concat('%',a,'%',b'%')
```

but what I want is starting, ending, middle should contain only non-alphanumeric. I am a newbie to regexp.

Answer (score 0):

```
CONCAT("[^[:alnum:]]", a, "[^[:alnum:]]+", b, "[^[:alnum:]]")
```

Or perhaps

```
CONCAT("\\b", a, "[^[:alnum:]]+", b, "\\b")
```